# Script started throwing "Reference error SpreadsheetApp is undefined "

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made an script for a Google Sheets. It's been a month since people used it and worked perfectly.

Basically the script looks in a spreadsheet, makes some formulas with the data and returns a value.

At the beginning of the script I call for "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()" function that returns me the actual spreadsheet. The problem is that sometimes the script returns an error that says "Reference error: SpreadsheetApp is undefined".

The weird thing is that if I close the Spreadsheet and open it again after 5 minutes (random time) the script works well! I can't find the error pattern. I don't know if it's something I made, or something from Google.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think its a Google Apps Script problem.  May be, for periods of time, SpreadshhetApp isn't available!  I've a script accessing 100+ times a day (time driven) to a GMail account.  Every day it fails a couple of time: GMail isn't available!

Answer (score 1):

Try open spreadsheet by ID

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById("0sdfksdlfkjsdlkfj_example_fdslkfjlsjkf");
```

Comment: I stopped having this problem. I think that reducing my execution time solved this issue. But I'm not certain so I don't really have the answer... sorry.